# How can I find the name of the Maven module a file belongs to?

Tags: maven

To optimize my CI builds, I want to run the test suites of only modules where files have changed since the last commit. I'm guessing I'll have to write my own solution here, but wondering if a simple solution exists.

Given a file name, does Maven have a way to determine which module it belongs to?

Example

```
pom.xml - Parent
  pom.xml - Child1
  pom.xml - Child2
     MyFile.java changed
```

So in this scenario, since only a file in `Child2` changed, I'd want to get the module name `Child2` from the string `child2/src/main/java/MyFile.java`